# C# Class variable issue

Tags: c#, variables

I'm a java programmer trying my hand at c#. I keep finding that VS will say the 'stock' variable in the following class will never be assigned to. What am I missing? Its assigned via the constructor...

```
using Factory;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Assembler : Builder
    {        
        Warehouse stock;

        public Assembler(Warehouse stock)
        {
            stock = this.stock;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is still wrong in java.. Juss sayin

Comment: Also, being a strong Java programmer usually means a harder time getting used to C# best practices as well.

Comment: The point of saying strong java programmer was to say that I have a java background, not to boast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.stock` refers to the class variable stock. Instead you should do `this.stock = stock`.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you are using VS to write your code, start learning how VS infers things for you.  For example, if you had right clicked on `stock` or `this.stock` you would have been able to select Go To Definition to see what each references of yours actually points to.  Or that when you have either of them selected, all identical references light up in your IDE.

Comment: I agree, this is incredibly useful, take advantage of it.